# hola que tal ,me podrian decir acerca este problema porfavor

Tags: macos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
tengo la duda de porque aparece este numero y no el nombre de mi macbook

Comment: Suena a que el hostname es una IP. ¿Cuál es el resultado de `echo $PS1`? ¿Usas bash o zsh?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta parece no relacionada con la temática del sitio.

Comment: me aparece esto cuando pongo el echo \h:\W \u\$ ,utilizo bash